# How to filter a HTML API response using XPath so that Requests can be chained in Insomnia REST Client

Tags: xpath, insomnia

If this is the raw data I can see in an API response from a simple GET request made on Insomnia to a website:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="abcdefg=" name="csrf-token" />
      </head>

      <body></body>
    </html>
```

How would I access the `csrf-token` value of `abcdefg` using XPATH if I am wanting to chain the response above such that I can use the csrf token in the headers another Insomnia request?

This is what is what I thought was correct: `head/meta[@name='csrf-param']`

If I only include `head/meta` the live preview is *Returned more than one result: head/meta*.

In the image below, you can see how this is set up but it appears that there is an "error" in the live response.

[Image of the error I see when I try to filter the response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdRf3.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the value of `abcdefg` from `csrf-token`:

```
//head/meta[@name='csrf-token']/@content
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were two instances of the respective element, e.g.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
        <meta content="abcdefg=" name="csrf-token" />
        <meta content="abcdefg=" name="csrf-token" />
      </head>

      <body></body>
    </html>
```

which is why I needed

```
(//meta[@name='csrf-token'])[1]/@content
```

*I know this doesn't answer the exact question but it extends the accepted answer and might help other people coming here.*